# What is beta/alpha testing on the developer console? How it is helpful for developer?

Tags: android, android-developer-api

There are three tabs in developer console 
1)Production
2) Beta Testing 
3) Alpha Testing

How Alpha and Beta is useful developer before publishing app in production?

How we can identify that how many users have latest updates?